# How to select all fieldsets in a form except the first one?

Tags: css

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<form id="aForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>fieldset 1</legend>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>fieldset 2</legend>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>fieldset 3</legend>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want all of the fieldsets except the first to have a margin above them, so I tried the following CSS:

```
#aForm fieldset:not(first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

I keep fiddling around with the CSS, trying different things, but I can't seem to figure out how to *not* select the first fieldset.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLwyK/

I know this is possible to do, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
#aForm fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGKde/)

**Unfortunately**, this is not supported in oldIE (IE8 and older), as you can see in [this post from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/#browser-support). An suggestion is to use general styling and then use `:first-child` to negate the styles which you don't want, for example:

```
#aForm fieldset {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#aForm fieldset:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
#aForm fieldset{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#aForm fieldset:first-child {
        margin-top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instead use the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) for better browser support:

```
#aForm fieldset ~ fieldset {
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLwyK/2/

Comment: That's absolutely normal. People go and downvote you but they don't have courage to explain.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the : of the selector

```
#aForm fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
```